# I need help for this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

Hi i'm trying to take some information from a python list of dictionaries and put them into javascript variables. But i keep getting this error at line 5. Can you help me ?
Here's the code :

```
    const i = [];
    const j = [];
    const total = [0];
    {% for item in dic %}
        i.push( {{ item.phase }} );
        if ({{ item.phase }} == 'Full Moon'){
            m.push([{{ item.number }},0])
            total.push({{ item.number }})
        };
        else {
            m.push([0,{{ item.number }}])
            total[0]+={{ item.number }}
        };
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I guess, from `if ({{ item.phase }} == 'Full Moon'){` that `item.phase` is a string, so, you need to quote it in javascript: `i.push( '{{ item.phase }}' );` and `if ('{{ item.phase }}' == 'Full Moon'){`

Comment: you're right the error come from that. Thank you very much for your help you saved me a lot of time